# Use doxygen to document and compare includes and their purpose

Tags: c++, c, doxygen

I want to use doxygen to document my code in high detail. One thing I want to document, is the "purpose" of single instances of includes of other .c/.h files. And with any chance to find out, if the documented "usage" of the includes meets reality.

Let's say I have an Include `#include <some_lib.h>`, with a big set of functions but only want or be allowed to use one or two of them, I want to document which I actually use. I would like to say something like:

```
/** 
  * Used elements:
  *  MY_MACRO()
  *  myFunction()
  *  myGlobal_Var()
  */
#include <some_lib.h>
```

Then I want Doxygen to produce some sort of documentation for that file using this information. Preferably a list containing every included file and the the promised items that are used from it.

It would be even better if there is a possibility to get Doxygen to produce a list of the actually used elements. But there are for sure tools out there to do this job.

A Reviewer or a script comparing those 2 results could then easily check if other items then the promised ones used in the implementation (and if the used ones are allowed). At the same time Doxygen will deliver the documentation of the items.

Do you know about a way to achieve this? And/Or have I failed to recognize a Doxygen built-in feature to bring me close to that goal?

Comment: There are cases where doxygen doesn't know which elements of a #include are used. For example, a header a.h can include b.h, and there can be multiple compilation units that include a.h and access b.h elements -- but doxygen doesn't necessarily know all of them. Given the lack of automation, a reader won't necessarily be able to trust that the list is up-to-date and complete.

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment. But lets say there is an implementation c.c that includes, a.h to access, b.h elements. Then doxygen should knows for c.c that this is the case, shouldn't it? If so, I can compare my promises in c.c against the actual usages; and if I additionally provide a list of forbidden elements (and their headers) then I can check against doxygens analysis of actual used elements (manually or by another little script). Or did I misunderstand something?